# Here SDK - Change map location

Tags: java, android

This is the sample code from Here API. But the problem I have is that the initial location where the map is loaded is wrong. What I need is for the map to be displayed where you are.

**What is the method that modifies the position of the map?**

```
private MapViewLite mapView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Get a MapViewLite instance from the layout.
    mapView = findViewById(R.id.map_view);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

private void loadMapScene() {
    // Load a scene from the SDK to render the map with a map style.
    mapView.getMapScene().loadScene(MapStyle.NORMAL_DAY, new MapScene.LoadSceneCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadScene(@Nullable MapScene.ErrorCode errorCode) {
            if (errorCode == null) {
                mapView.getCamera().setTarget(new GeoCoordinates(52.530932, 13.384915));
                mapView.getCamera().setZoomLevel(14);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "onLoadScene failed: " + errorCode.toString());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the piece of code that hard codes the position:

```
mapView.getCamera().setTarget(new GeoCoordinates(52.530932, 13.384915))
```

Instead, set the coordinates to be the user's click. In order to do so, you will need to surround that piece of code with an `onTouch()` listener and check the action of the user. I'll use an ImageView as an example. So something like this:

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            //whatever you want to do
            //to fetch the coordinates of the user's click use event.getX() and event.getY()
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please tell me in which way it is possible to obtain the coordinates by clicking on the map?